# How to force strong password in primefaces p:password

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, passwords

I'm creating a registration form. I want to force that p:password is strong. Is there any way to validate that p:password is strong? I want to be taken as 'strong' the same indicator of p:password's feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by your final sentence?

Comment: When feedback="true" the p:password show a indication when password is strong. So, I want to force that p:password is strong as the feedback indicate. Sorry for my english.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a built in way to get what the password strength is. I found this [link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18287) which it seems like you can use. I could be wrong and PrimeFaces might have this functionality embedded now, but not that I've seen. I think that component will do everything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this:

```
<h:form id="form" >
    <p:password  value="#{regitroCtrl.usuario.contrasenia}"
                 id="contrasena"
                 feedback="true"   
                 required="true"   
                 onblur="validarPassword()"/>
    <p:message for="contrasena" id="contrasenaMsg" />

    <p:commandButton value="Registrarse"
                     action="#{regitroCtrl.registrarse()}"
                     update="form"
                     onclick="return validarPassword()"/>
</h:form>
```

The validarPassword function:

```
function validarPassword(){
    var strength = PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.testStrength($("#form\\:contrasena").val());
    if(strength <= 30){
        $("#form\\:contrasenaMsg").html('<span class="ui-message-error-icon"></span><span class="ui-message-error-detail">Por favor, ingresa una contraseña más fuerte</span>');
        $("#form\\:contrasena").addClass("ui-state-error");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#form\\:contrasenaMsg").html('');
        $("#form\\:contrasena").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is [no build-in solution](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12899&sid=6da533b56d7cbdb7f2e67f932ce37356) for your requirement. Only I can see it in [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml) is password feed back

```
 <p:password id="pwd" value="#{passwordView.password3}" feedback="true"
      weakLabel="Weak" goodLabel="Good" strongLabel="Strong"/>
```

Alternately you can use validator

```
   <p:password id="pwd" value="#{passwordView.password3}" feedback="true"
      weakLabel="Weak" goodLabel="Good" strongLabel="Strong">
      <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="101"/> // or
      <f:validator  validatorId="passwordValidator" />
   </p:password>
```

Validation class

```
  @ManagedBean
  @RequestScoped
  @FacesValidator(value = "passwordValidator")
  public class PasswordValidator implements Validator, Serializable {

  @Override
 public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object propertyValue) throws ValidatorException {
    // your validation here 
 }
```